# Getting a PHP filePointer to load an image

Tags: php, sql, image

I have stored my image pointers in a mysql database so now I just want to print the image using the `<img>` tag.

I got the variable image for the database to give me the pointer to the image....
for this certain page (and example) it gives me this pointer

```
$Image = '/xampp/htdocs/cw/mysql/images/Iphone3GSh.JPG'
```

and my `<img>` does that doesn't out the image is

```
<img src="<?php echo $Image; ?>" />
```

Comment: What type of error are you getting?

Comment: The image tag expects a file reference relative to the web root, not the filesystem root

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the important step to convert the local path to the file (what you call pointer is normally named *file-path*) into an URI. This can be done as pure data-uri (not suitable for larger images):

```
$ImageSrc = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($Image));

<img src="<?php echo $ImageSrc; ?>" />
```

Normally you convert the file-path into it's URI equivalent based on the webroot configured with your webserver. As you have not shared it with your question this can only be roughly shown here:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$rootLen = strlen($root);
if (substr($Image, 0, $rootLen) !== $root) {
    throw new Exception('Incompatible File');
}
$ImageSrc = substr($Image, $rootLen);

<img src="<?php echo $ImageSrc; ?>" />
```

Please consult the HTML reference of your choice to learn about the very basics of the HTML image tag, what the src is for, what it takes, what an URI is and how all this works. It would be a bit too much to explain you all this in an answer, so I only posted PHP code, which might or might not, create more problems for you as you already have. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, nice to see there are still people willing to put effort out to help others. Have a nice day!